# CommonDialog components should to be disposed?

Tags: .net, winforms, idisposable

Using code blocks or Dispose method hasn't used in this [MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20170730010221/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx) example about dialog boxes.

But why it is not disposed despite it has Dispose method ?

Comment: to me it looks like a bad sample, it should be disposing ... its not a critical flaw since the GC should sort it out.

Comment: The sample was fixed somewhere between [July 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170730010221/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.aspx) and [May 2018](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmya, that is not crystal clear unfortunately.  OpenFileDialog and friends inherit Dispose() from the Component class.  Every component must implement Dispose() because the Dispose() method of the form calls it.  It just so happens to be that there are several Component derived classes that have a do-nothing Dispose() method.  The dialog classes are like that, they are dialogs.  They clean up any unmanaged resources when the dialog closes.  No additional help is needed.

This isn't exactly documented well.  It's somewhat visible, the MSDN Library shows that the method was inherited, not overridden by the class.  Which still doesn't make it obvious that bypassing the inherited Component.Dispose() method is okay (it is).  If you are uncomfortable with it, many programmers are, then don't hesitate to wrap it with the *using* statement.  It does no harm to call a Dispose() method that doesn't do anything.  Well, not the kind of harm you'd be ever be able to measure.

Comment: For the record, the sample was fixed somewhere between July 2017 and May 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Well their finalizer will be eventually called by the garbage collector, and since they don't hold (many) unmanaged resources (and certainly nothing like open file handles), they didn't bother with it for an example.

Besides, how many times do you think a file dialog is typically shown in an application's life time?

Comment: It honestly depends on the application, how it works, and how it's used by the user. Someone could be opening file dialogs left and right.

Comment: @rossisdead, of course, and the choice to call `Dispose` is available to you if needed. But in general, letting it get garbage collected should be good enough! (I bet this is how the Chrome memory leak issue first started)

Comment: I'm not so sure I agree. You never know how someone else is going to end up using it(say, for example, it's being used in a custom control that someone else can't access the code to). Rather than make a hard to find bug, it'd just easier to make sure you Dispose of it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The Garbage Collector cleans up after you if you haven't explicitly called `Dispose()`.
Most of the time, you can rely on the Garbage Collector to do that for you, unless you're very specific about clearing up minute memory usage after every single build-up.